# $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles iff $a \cos B+b \cos C+c \cos A = \frac12(a+b+c)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles if and only if 
$$a \cos B+b \cos  C+c \cos A = \frac12(a+b+c)$$

Comment: This isn't your first question, far from that. You should have read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) by now.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Law of Cosines?

Comment: yes , I am familiar with the law of cosines

Comment: What are your thoughts? We don't know if this is an exercise you're asking us to solve (which we won't unless you've at least tried yourself). We don't know your background, the tools you have, we know nothing other than a question which is identical to its title!

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines and then http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html and finally $$\sin X+\sin Y+\sin Z$$ where $X=A-B$ etc. with  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that the left-hand side of your equation is given by
$$a\left(\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ac}\right)+b\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right)+c\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)=$$